# Is the »uns« here a case of dativus ethicus?

Tags: translation, semantics

> (530) Sokrates: Willkommen dem Ion! Woher kommst du ***[uns](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/platons-werke-erster-theil-7316/23)* jetzt
>   gewandert**?

First, I would like to know if **uns** here is a case of *dativus ethicus* (is there anything like that in German)?

Then, finally, I would like to know how I am to translate into English the whole sentence. Though I know all the words, it seems to make no sense at all, especially the last part of it, **uns jetzt gewandert**.

No German dictionary that I know of records **wandern** as needing an indirect object like **uns**.

So a literal translation of this sentence would then be:

> (530) Socrates: Welcome to Ion [*dem Ion*]! Where are you coming from
>   [*Woher kommst du*] to us [*uns*] now wandered about [*jetzt gewandert*]?

Comment: There actually is a  *dativus ethicus* in German.

Comment: Regarding your request for translation into English, or for suggestions for adequate idioms for the complex "Wo kommst du uns jetzt denn her?" (yes, I varied the text a bit, on purpose), this seems rather to be a question for the Stackexchange English forum, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Nope. I have yet to get an answer explaining to me the function, if any, of that _uns_ there; and whether it is a case of dativus ethicus. And it is in the context of this problem that I also asked for a secondary explanation of how this whole sentence might be rendered into English (not a translation as such, which I can always find and read on the Internet). So... nope.

Comment: The German dictionary is for modern German. Nobody would build the sentence like that ourdays. Now we would say: „Woher kommst du jetzt gewandert?” I never heard of “Dativus ethicus” before, but according to what I now have read, I'd say this isn't the case here. Probably it comes from „zu jemandem wandern” (like „zu jemandem gehen”). And I'd say it's „uns” instead of „mir” because it's a kind of “pluralis majestatis”.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer Even in modern German, why would one add "jetzt gewandert" at the end of this sentence: "Woher kommst du jetzt gewandert”? If you try to translate it into English, the end result would not make too much sense: "Where are you coming from now wandered?" So my problem of intelligibility persists. Why would one add that participle at the end of that sentence? What is its grammatical function? If the sentence had simply read "Woher kommst du jetzt?," it would have made perfect sense, both in my mind and in English, and even in German, by all accounts. But that participle ruins it.

Comment: @user26328 I think in this sentence the word “jetzt” is not there to express the time. (Using the present would suffice.) The word expresses that the speaking person is bugged out because of the situation. It's like “Was willst du jetzt?“ Which includes a hint of “I am already tired, don't annoy me too.”

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer And what about the past participle, "gewandert," that comes after it? Your explanation of "jetzt" seems satisfactory to me; so this adverb is here used as a modal particle, like "noch," "nur," etc., right?

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer *Dativus Ethicus* is **still** present in modern German - Everyone might have heard a "Komm du  mir bloß nach Hause!" when he was a teenager.

Answer (score 1):

That's a toughie!  May I have a shot?

Regarding your first question: Yes. (as @tofro wrote in their comment)

As for your second request, let's start with a counter example.
Please translate LITERALLY (into German), without consulting a dictionary:

> She's walking out on me.

I bet that you've come up with something really ugly (so did I, by the way).
Now, let's put a cherry on top of the sentence.  She's doing it NOW.  Translate,
literally:

> She's walking out on me now!

I have 2 results for you:

```
Sie ist gehend hinaus auf mir nun. (my translation)
Sie geht jetzt auf mich hinaus. (translate.google.co.uk)
```

A quick question, before we continue our work of destruction, sorry, translation: 
What's the opposite of "walking out on somebody"?  Let's say it is "walking IN on somebody".

Back to the sentence you have found:
Woher kommst du uns jetzt gewandert?

Applying our translation technique, I get roughly:

> Wherefrom are you now wandering in on us?

Is this the final answer? 
Yes, final answer.
Right. Now let's move on to the third sentence ... (I can't wait!)

Friedrich Schleiermacher: Platons Werke - Kapitel 32
http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/platons-werke-2430/32

Why does it start with a lower case letter?

Comment: While I very much appreciate your answer, and the deconstructive humour of it, I don't think that "Wherefrom are you now wandering in on us?" is the final answer. Why? Because in your English rendition there is only one verb, while in the German original there are two. Then the original sentence would have had to be like this: Woher wanderst du uns jetzt?

Comment: Alright. Final final then: Wherefrom cometh you now wandering in on us?

Comment: I really like it. But it's rather cumbersome like this, at least to a modern mind, isn't it? And yes, that's the final final answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.  I feel the same - the text is hard to read, but I enjoy that sort of writing style from time to time.

Comment: Yes, me too. That's why I am trying to read it, although some might argue, and not entirely without a sense of being right in their observation, that this is too much for me, too complex, too difficult, etc. But this is my way of learning German, by leaps and bounds, one day still learning vocabulary by rote, the other sinking my mind's teeth into such raw meat, as texts like these can offer me.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach.  For short bursts of intensity I recommend Schopenhauer's translation of Gracian's Orakel der Weltklugheit. http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/gracians-orakel-der-weltklugheit-3064/3

Comment: Thank you. I do appreciate the link and everything else. Hope I can "see" you again in the nether region of my future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for insight is grouping the words differently as already suggested in the question comments and Stefan's answer.

> Woher kommst du **uns jetzt** gewandert? (surprised)
>
> Woher kommst du **jetzt** gewandert? (annoyed)
>
> Woher kommst du gewandert? (neutral)

The strikingly unnecessary piece is **uns jetzt**. **Jetzt** functions for specifying the time. But it may also specify the mood.

Imagine Sokrates making a greeting gesture with both arms, embracing the person who had approached.

You cannot use a plain *jetzt*. That is because that particle expresses you are disturbed.

> Was ist los? (neutral)
>
> Was ist **jetzt** los? (slightly annoyed)
>
> Was ist **jetzt wieder** los? (very annoyed)

See how these particles which seem to specify a time/repetition in fact specify a mood?

Of course, Sokrates don't want to express annoyance but respect so he has to embrace the other person with his words, too. That is the purpose of **uns**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that apparently is a case of *dativus ethicus*. This form is used to express special interest or judgement of the person(s) in dative in the ongoing action.

English has no modern way to express this (Shakespeare still could - "Rob me the exchequer" [Falstaff] is about the only example I could find, here meaning: "do that *for* me").

Dativus ethicus is not really present in contemporary German - With maybe one major exception: Education.

Parents tend to use the dativus ethicus in expressing expectations towards their children:

> Dass du mir bloß keine Dummheiten machst, solange du bei Oma bist!
>
> Komm du mir mal nach Hause!

Would roughly translate to "**I** definitely want you to ..."

This translation obviously would not fit to your example - There, the dative would rather be translated to something like

> **We** wonder where from you have been wandering to us.

(Simply stressing the personal interest)

We might still wonder why there are two verbs "kommen" and "wandern" in the sentence - There should be a simple explanation for that: "kommen" simply denotes arrival, could be from next door or a foreign country. "wandern" (which wouldn't have been understood as "hiking" in ancient Greece, but rather as "travelling") makes it clear that he came from far away. If you leave out one of the verbs, you'd be missing its respective aspect.

With this aspect in the translation, you might want to modify the above sentence to

> We wonder where from you have been travelling that you now arrive here?

Comment: So two things out of three are now crystal clear to me. 1. Yes, it is a case of dativus ethicus, as I have thought all along. 2. _Jetzt_ is indeed something of a modal particle there rather than just a simple adverb of time. These things are very clear now. The only remaining mystery is, to me, why there are two verbs in that sentence instead of one: both _kommen_ and _wandern_. Shouldn't only one of them have been enough?

Comment: See  my extended answer